# Removing File from current directory

Tags: c, file

I am trying to remove a file from the current working directory. When I try to make it print "Invalid file" when file is not found, it throws me a segmentation fault. This snippet is part of a bigger program.

Code:

```
printf("\nEnter your current password:\t");
scanf("%s",temp2);
comp2 = strcmp(password,temp2);
file = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
if(comp2 == 0)
{
    int value;
    printf("\nEnter the file name:\t");
    scanf("%s",file);
    sprintf(cmd,"rm -i %s",file);
    value=system(cmd);
    if(value == -1)
        printf("\nFile not Found. Exiting Program");
}
else
    printf("\nThe password is incorrect. Please try again.");
break;
```

Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `cmd` allocated?  Also, `rm -i` is an interactive command but you're not an interactive process.  Also, C has an `unlink` call so you don't have to use `system`...

Comment: How about using [remove](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/remove.html) ([caveats](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO08-C.+Take+care+when+calling+remove%28%29+on+an+open+file)) or [unlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/unlink.html)?

Comment: Executing `rm` in a subprocess isn't a good way to delete files from a C program.  It's open to all sorts of potential problems, such as an unusual `$PATH` causing `rm` not to be found, or spaces in the filename causing `rm` to misunderstand what file you're trying to delete.  Use a system call, such as `unlink`, to make your *own* program delete the file instead of running some *other* program to delete it.

Comment: you read a password of unbounded length into a fixed buffer? That cries buffer overflow. Same for reading the filename. Is `cmd` big enough to accomodate `file` and the command? Even if it is, follow Wyzards advice. Finally, i suggest you signal successful completion somehow too...

Comment: How did you declare variable `cmd`?

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out my mistakes and directing me towards the solution. unlink worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remove function

```
remove(file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use remove(path) - it removes file or directory.